# Profiler tab not coming in visualvm for remote jmx connection

Tags: java, profiling, profiler, visualvm, jvisualvm

Am trying to profile a remote tomcat appln which is my staging env. But I am unable to get the profiler tab. Tried googling but I couldnt find the exact issue here. 
Both my remote and local jdk versions are same. Both are java 8. Am using visualvm 1.3.8

Comment: Tried a clean install already ? Checked the Plugins if others work and can be installed / Updated ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I tried clean install. Have removed .visualvm and cache folders as well. But no help. I could see the profiler tab if trying with a local tomcat app.

Comment: I don't see profiler tab for jvisualVm itself

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Profiling of remote application is not supported, please use 'Sampler' tab instead.

Comment: Could you please provide the link which says that 'Profiler' is not available for remote applications? java.net is no longer available.

Comment: https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/visualvm/visualvm.java.net.backup/master/www/applications_remote.html

Comment: Wow, really ? did they upgrade it now ?